# Why is there parsing ambiguity in accessing a list in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, parsing, grammar

In postgres it allows doing:

```
SELECT (ARRAY[1,2])[1] AS a
```

But it does not allow:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2][1] AS a
```

This seems a bit arbitrary to me that it would be ambiguous when not including parens around the array literal, what would be an example where this would be ambiguous? Most languages have a construct of a direct array access, so curious why it's considered ambiguous in PG.

Comment: Wild guess: In the second case, it's not sure if you're trying to index a one-dimensional array or create a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @EdmCoff yea that seems to be it, since it doesn't specify the array dimensions like it would in C, but it seems to infer that when parsing the literal.